# Scan a dynamodb table and using contains on a list with go sdk

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a dynamodb field that looks like this:
`[ { "S" : "test@gmail.com" }, { "S" : "test2@gmail.com" } ]`

I am trying to run a scan to return any record that e.g. contain `test@gmail.com` . I am not sure I should use contains to do this, it's currently not returning any records, any pointers as to what I should use?

My go is setup like this:

```
type Site struct {
    ID           string       `json:"id"`
    Site         string       `json:"site"`
    Emails []string `json:"emails,omitempty"`
}
```

```
func (ds *datastore) GetEmail(email string, out interface{}) error {

    filt := expression.Name("emails").Contains(strings.ToLower(email))

    fmt.Println("Get Email", filt)
    //filt := expression.Contains(expression.Name("emails"), expression.Value(email))

    proj := expression.NamesList(
        expression.Name("emails"),
        expression.Name("site"),
    )
    expr, err := expression.NewBuilder().
        WithFilter(filt).
        WithProjection(proj).
        Build()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    scanInput := &dynamodb.ScanInput{
        ExpressionAttributeNames:  expr.Names(),
        ExpressionAttributeValues: expr.Values(),
        FilterExpression:          expr.Filter(),
        ProjectionExpression:      expr.Projection(),
        TableName:                 aws.String(ds.TableName),
    }

    result, err := ds.DDB.Scan(scanInput)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("what is the err", err)
        return err
    }

    if len(result.Items) == 0 {
        fmt.Println("No Email found")
        return errors.New(http.StatusText(http.StatusNotFound))
    }

    err = ds.Marshaler.UnmarshalMap(result.Items[0], out)

    return err
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing a contains on a partial email it won't match when the filter is applied to a set. It will have to be an exact email match.

```
{
    "Email": "test@gmail.com"
}
// This will match a contains on "test@g"

{
    "Emails": ["test@gmail.com", "another@gmail.com"]
}
// this will not match a contains on "test@g" but will match a contains of "test@gmail.com"
```

See contains: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html

Also note you're doing a scan. Scans perform poorly in Dynamodb as soon as your data is of any significant size. Think of storing your data in a different format so you query it via partition keys or use an AWS RDS as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks, yes I figured out that I was doing it right but the scan was paginating results.  I am creating a query with a key.